# MYSQL Query split by month

Tags: mysql

At the moment I have a MYSQL query that looks like this...

```
 SELECT distinct devid,username FROM auth_log WHERE MONTH(accesstime) = 1;
```

This would return all of January which is what I want.  Is it possible to return an array or something like that as a single query for a whole year or date range but split by month thus saving me from having to run multiple queries like.

```
SELECT distinct devid,username FROM auth_log WHERE MONTH(accesstime) = 1;
SELECT distinct devid,username FROM auth_log WHERE MONTH(accesstime) = 2;
SELECT distinct devid,username FROM auth_log WHERE MONTH(accesstime) = 3;
```

Comment: Just query the range of months (whichever method floats your boat) and then order by the month/access time...    You cannot get an array of arrays.. But it will be a result set that would be ordered by the months.. Then on the front end just have it interpret the month..

Comment: Oh.. And make sure to add the month to the result selet i.e. select distinct MONTH(accesstime) as r.month   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just get

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    MONTH(accesstime) AccessTimeMonth, 
    devid,
    username 
FROM auth_log
```

and do your filtering work in the front end?

Comment: Perfect, that way I can graph it easily too!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct MONTH(accesstime), devid,username 
   FROM auth_log 
   WHERE MONTH(accesstime) in ( 1, 2, 3 )
```

or

where month(accesstime) between 1 and

12

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct devid, username FROM auth_log WHERE MONTH(accesstime) >= 1 AND MONTH(accesstime) <= 12 ORDER BY MONTH(accesstime);
```

Could be cleaned up.. but just one of MANY variations that could be used